# Clearing white space created by relative positioning and keeping the moved object unaffected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which is placed near the header. When I click on it, the div moves down towards the center of the page (I'm using the jquery animate function).

Once the div has moved to the center of the page I want the other elements (the other div's which are placed near the header) to fill the white space which was left because of the div which moved to the center of the page.

I have successfully removed the white space and other elements have filled the space.

The main problem is, when taking care of the left white space the div which is now in the center is also being affected!

Click on the first element: http://jsfiddle.net/maven123/vpumfujd/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".icons").click(function () {
         var icon_position = $(this).offset();
        $(this).animate({
            left: (window.outerWidth / 2) - icon_position.left-400,
            top: (window.outerHeight / 2) - icon_position.top
        }, 1200, function () {
            $(this).css({
                position:"relative",
                marginLeft:"-100px"
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Well of course it gets affected by the negative `margin-left` you set on it … if you don’t want that, don’t set that margin (and use another way to make the remaining elements move left).

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: Once a box has moved to the middle, should it be frozen in place?

Comment: I’d probably switch the box to absolute positioning to move it to the middle, and animate a margin-left for the next box after it from 100px to 0.

Comment: it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @CBroe, please post that as an answer!! it solved my problem xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it gets affected by the negative `margin-left` you set on it; if you don’t want that, don’t set that margin, and use another way to make the remaining elements move left.

I’d suggest to switch the box to absolute positioning to move it to the middle, and animate `margin-left` for the next box after it from 100px to 0.

Comment: Well that's great, i found a solution base on Cbroe directives, but feel free to post that as an aswer and i will surely vote it up